# URL Rewrite rule IIS with special character

Tags: windows, iis, url-rewrite-module

Im trying to write a rewrite rule in IIS so that if any user that tries to hit the following url:

http://mydomain/page/#/db/user

Then gets redirected to http://mydomain:8443

Any idea on how to do it?

Im able to do it only until http://mydomain/page but when i enter /#/db/user in the rule, it wont take it.

Thanks!!

Comment: Things after `#` are not sent to server side at all by browsers. That's how URLs work so you have no way to change that.

Comment: Do you mean that the special character does not work in redirection? If yes, you only need to encode your special characters, and then url rewrite, about how to encode special characters, you can refer to this link: https://www.urlencoder.org.